# create an a x b expanded grid memory efficiently

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, data.table

Probably a very simple question but I would like to be able to set the variables, `a`and `b` to be able to create an data.frame or data.table from expand.grid in R.

e.g. if `a=5`,`b=3`

what i want i to be able to get the same output as

```
expand.grid(seq(0,1,by=1/5),seq(0,1,by=1/5), seq(0,1,by=1/5))
```

and if `a=3`, and `b=4` i would get

```
expand.grid(seq(0,1,by=1/3), seq(0,1,by=1/3), seq(0,1,by=1/3), seq(0,1,by=1/3))
```

i.e. `b` is the number of columns....and `a` is the interval size.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Ideally I would be putting in numbers for `a` approximately 100 and `b` approximately 30 is there something that is quick and memory efficient at producing that...perhaps something form `data.table`?

Comment: With a=100 and b=30, you're going to get 100^30 = 1e60 rows. All the storage in the world won't hold that. You may want to rethink your problem.

Comment: hmm...good point...will have a bit of a re-think....

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work, using `replicate` and `do.call`

```
exgrid <- function(a, b){
  do.call(expand.grid,replicate(b , seq(0,1,by = 1/a), simplify = FALSE))
}
```

Comment: Thanks i know I didn't specify in the question but...i was thinking of putting in some fairly large numbers (a~100 and b~30) in the function...is there anything that is a bit less memory intensive?

Comment: @ h.l.m see Hong Ooi's comment on your question. Think about the size of your problem in terms of the RAM / disk space you need. While data.table is memory efficient, it can't make objects smaller than their inherent size.

Answer (score 3):

This will generate a data.frame (an ffdf) with 100 Mio rows without memory issues. It uses package ff. You can increase the columns as you like. Mark that this can generate quite some data if you play around with the columns.

```
require(ffbase)
x <- expand.ffgrid(ff(1:1000), ff(1:1000), ff(1:100))
dim(x)
x[1:5, ]
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this gets you close to what you need:

```
b <- 4    
expand.grid(rep(list(seq(0,1,by=1/3)), b))
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry i should have specified in the question originally...but have edited my question to ask for something that is a bit less memory intensive...

Comment: afraid data.table is about speed efficiency - not memory efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

```
> require('ffbase')
> require('BioGeoBEARS')

#https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/BioGeoBEARS/versions/0.2.1/topics/expand.grid.jc
> system.time(mtx <- expand.ffgrid(ff(mcS$from), ff(mcS$to)))
#user  system elapsed 
#4.45    3.30    9.74 

> system.time(mtx <- expand.grid(mcS$from, mcS$to))
#user  system elapsed 
#1.92    0.25    2.18 

> system.time(mtx <- expand.grid.alt(mcS$from, mcS$to))
#user  system elapsed 
#8.05    0.95    9.03 

> system.time(mtx <- expand.grid.jc(mcS$from, mcS$to))
#user  system elapsed 
#0.44    0.17    0.61
```

Although the timing for evaluate is faster, but the normal `expand.grid()` will take longer time to read the object `mtx` than `expand.ffgrid()`.

added info (datasize) :

```
> as_data_frame(mtx)
# A tibble: 100,000,000 x 2
    from    to
   <int> <int>
 1   101   126
 2   126   126
 3   192   126
 4    19   126
 5    66   126
 6    82   126
 7   143   126
 8     1   126
 9    88   126
10   168   126
# ... with 99,999,990 more rows
```